# pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN ERROR?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to capture the MOUSEBUTTONDWON and MOUSEBUTTONUP events seperately to help me with my click and drag code. But when press the mouse button down the event is also captured by the pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP event!

The code is located below:

```
import pygame

LEFT = 1

running = 1
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 200))

while running:
 event = pygame.event.poll()
 if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
     running = 0
 elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
     print "You pressed the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos
 elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == LEFT:
     print "You released the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos

 screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
 pygame.display.flip()
```

When I click the left mouse button down both the statements are printed when they shouldn't be.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: When I run your code I don't get the same behavior as you. I only get MOUSEBUTTONDOWN events at mouse down and MOUSEBUTTONUP events at mouse up. However, it seems to miss some of them. Try to avoid filling the screen and flipping the buffer at every event (you also get timer events IIRC) as it slows down the program a lot, maybe that will fix the problem for you.

Comment: The code is working for me without problems, too. But maybe you should read all  pending events before updating the screen, eg "for event in pygame.event.get()".

Comment: I fugured out that the code starts going wrong when i add the VIDEORESIZE event like so

Comment: import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
    from sys import exit

    LEFT = 1
    size = 520,630
    running = 1
    #screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 200))
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, RESIZABLE, 32)
    while running:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
     if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
         running = 0
     if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:

Comment: size = event.size
        pygame.display.set_caption("Window resized to "+str(event.size)) 
     elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
         print "You pressed the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos
     elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == LEFT:
         print "You released the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos
     screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, RESIZABLE, 32)
     screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
     pygame.display.flip()

Comment: The code works fine for me. Could you provide other information, like pygame and python versions used? If we can reproduce the problem we could provide some answer. Besides, there may be other people out there facing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be because you have a problem Pygame installation.
Reinstall Pygame.

Try this link instead of the one on the official website: [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame). Make sure that you download the installer for the **version of Python you are using**, as well as **the amount of bits you installed Python in**. You can get the version of Python by loading up the interpreter, and looking at the top line that reads something like:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] on win32
```

Where the version number is on the left, and the number of bits are on the right.